# grails error: The requested resource is not available

Tags: grails

Can you tell me why I would get an HTTP Status 404 resource not available error when adding a new action to my controller in the following trivial way:

- First, I added a statement, println "in list action", to the list action which Grails generated, to make sure I'm seeing the file updates made to the controller.  This println then comes out on the console.
- I added a new action "abc" in the controller, directly copying its code from the index action, i.e. making it simply redirect to the list action.

When I enter the browser address: http://localhost:8080/myApp/user/abc it returns resource not available.  Re-starting grails did not help.  If I enter http://localhost:8080/myApp/user/index, it works as expected.

Thanks

Comment: is your action a closure or a method?  also, showing us the controller code would help

Comment: Are you using a clean new Grails application? If not, you might have fiddled with security filters, URL mappings or whatever. Are there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson Learned:  If you get this behavior, make sure you don't have incorrect code syntax in another action.

---

I resolved this strange situation (to an extent anyway!).  It turns out I was missing a closing brace in my top/first action, but had an extra closing brace in my second action.  Don't know how this could have compiled, but apparently it did, as when I added sample new test actions further down, they worked eventually (which seemed strange).  When I fixed the parenthesis issue, the second action worked then also

Note, I am doing current Grails examples without using a full blown IDE, so perhaps the IDE would have caught this error.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it using Grails 1.3.7.  You can safely end a controller action with `redirect(action: "index")`, and it won't throw an error.

I'm guessing you did this:

```
def index = { [foo: "bar"] }
def abc = { [foo: "bar"] }
```

In that case, you'd need a dedicated view for both `index` and `abc`.

If you instead do this:

```
def abc = { redirect(action: "index") }
```

You'll get redirected correctly.

Comment: OverZealous, for abc I did:  def abc = {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }.  This then produced the "resource not available" error when attempting to access action abc.

Comment: I'm using the same Grails version.  Please note I updated the previous comment.

Comment: Does your `list` action have a view?

Comment: If you want more support, you *need* to post your controller, as recommended in a comment above.

Comment: The list action shows just fine, referencing it explicitly via .../list, or via .../index.  But .../abc doesn't work.  Are you able to duplicate that?  Thanks

Comment: I went to post the code and now it works.  This seems like a class caching problem.  The weird thing is I updated a println statement to make sure the edits were coming thru, and they were, so ??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a view to go along with your action? Normally you would have a 
    grails-app/views/user/abc.gsp

If you don't have a view you will get a 404 error since your controler will try and direct your browser to a page that does not exist.

Comment: Jared, why does a view need to be created, for an action that does a redirect?   For example, the standard save action doesn't have a save.gsp with it, does it.     Does one need to tell grails about every action they have?

Answer (score 0):

Had that same error, and **fixed** it by forcing my project to recompile completely. That means, I **deleted the content of my `out` directory** with all the `.class` files. Re-running the project then re-built all files and the intended controller action was available.